# PC has a ping of 300ms if other PC is on

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ping

A router is connected to a access point via powerline. On the access point are two computers, one via WLAN **PC (A)** and another via LAN **PC (B**):

[image]

- When **PC (B)** is not on, **PC (A)** has a normal ping (40-50ms) and 30Mbit download-rate (there is only a 30 Mbit internet connection, so that is max).
- When **PC (B)** is on

  - and **PC (A)** is connected to the accesspoint, then it has a ping of 300 and a download rate from 11 Mbit.
  - and **PC (A)** is connected via powerline, then it has a ping of 300 and a download rate from 11 Mbit.
  - and **PC (A)** is connected via WLAN to the router then it has a good ping (15ms) and 30 Mbit download-rate.

**PC (A)** and **PC (B)** belong to two brothers. The father does not allow to put a whole in the wall for a lan cable, so one of them is doomed to use wlan or powerline. Its also not allowed to lay a lan cable through the flat to improve the original router signal.

The router is a netgear nighthawk xr300. Unfortunately its not a solution to connect the router with **PC (A)** because of the distance (the above good ping was only reached when moving **PC (A)** in the room from the router).

The lucky lan brother with **PC (B)** does not cooperate and there is no way to get access to his **PC (B)** to check what he is doing there that causes such a high ping.

First I thought maybe the lucky lan brother is either hardcore downloading stuff or may have some maleware that causes the high ping rate. But then I don't understand why **PC (A)** has a good ping/download-rate when its connected directly to the router. The main problem is the bad ping when **PC (B)** is on. When I visit them next time, I will try to enable **Anti-Bufferbloat** from the router. However, I don't think that this will fix the ping problem, because even when **PC (A)** had a terrible ping as 300, the download-rate from 11 Mbit was still acceptable.

I tried out another access point and I tried some other devices (instead of **PC (B)**) but I had on all devices a ping around 300, when connected to the access point while **PC (A)** was on.

Any clues or ideas what could cause the high ping and how I could fix it?

Comment: So it's specifically when PC (B) is connected to something via Ethernet? Have you tried monitoring what PC (B) sends/receives over the network (e.g. using Wireshark)?

Comment: @grawity yes its specifically only when PC (B) is conneted via Ethernet + Powerline. PC (B)'s ping is also good (40ms). I have not tried that yet. I will try Wireshark and I will try if I find something in the log files of the router when I visit them today.

Comment: It is likely the case (but without access to PC (B), it remains speculation) that PC (B) is generating lots of traffic, and that QoS is active, prioritizing PC (B) over PC(A). In this case, the father should intervene and PC (B) should be checked out as well as the router. Keep in mind, if the upload is clogged, the download will stall and thus the ping will shoot up and the download becomes slower than what it is capable of. This is a clear upload is maxed out issue. Usually the case with downloading torrents.

Comment: 40ms ping to somewhere inside the same subnet is still massively out of whack - even allowing for powerline being pretty slow. Powerline might add 1 or 2 ms itself, but same subnet ping ought to be around 1ms, not 40.

Comment: @Tetsujin I bet they do a speedtest on an internet site, so the ping shows the ping to the server. That would also explain the increase to 300.

Comment: @LPChip - only on my first coffee, my bad ;) I hadn't considered this was being measured by speedtest etc. 40ms to nearest public node is still pretty slow though. I'm about 6 - 8ms

Comment: @Tetsujin when I was on cable internet, I had a ping of about 16 ms on a speedtest. I'm now on a slower ADSL and I have a ping of around 30. 40ms is not uncommon depending on your connection. I've seen it before.

Comment: @LPChip - hmm, you're probably right. I haven't had DSL in over a decade, so I'm just used to the snappier responses, I guess.

Comment: @Tetsujin you are right, we were measuring ms over speedtest. Does `Anti-Bufferbloat` does also limit upload capacity for each PC? Torrents would be a possibilty. Thank you for suggesting it. I will check the upload rates.

Comment: @Tetsujin but if it were torrents, then the ms in the speedtest should be also at 300 when connecting to the main router, right?

Comment: The router may be doing better QoS. I would think that brother's computer is heavily infected and is busy bombarding the Internet, rather than his doing downloads all day. His Internet might be lousy, too.